# Getting install.php when export site from development server to production

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I've copied files and imported DB dump to MySQL on production server but when I try to access website settings.php file loads. I've got settings.php file in my site subdirectory in /sites folder. Here's it's content:

```
$databases = array('default' => array('default' => array(
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'database' => 'dmitry_dkkb',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'fg67klbn0',
    'host' => '127.0.0.1')));
```

I guess i just missed something when i edited this file

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the drive to mysqli. Also, follow this steps:
1) Take a back up of your db and save it to a safe place
2) Remove all the tables from the db, and remove the setting.php or rename it
3) Do you clean install of Drupal using those files
4) Once finished, import the db back up

This process always works on all platforms, in all the situation

Comment: Now only main page loads, but others return 404.

Comment: Did you copy the .htaccess file?

Comment: @Dimitry Did you follow the steps I mentioned?